# Where to generate OAuth 2.0 Secret Key for iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Where to generate OAuth 2.0 secret key for my iOS application?

Here are my console screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Do I miss something? I know that I can generate OAuth 2.0 secret key from Web OAuth 2.0, but I am not sure whether it can be used for iOS app.

Comment: Web oauth cannot be used for other services like mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

You does not need for oauth secret key for ios app, You can make auth of your users with client id only, please see this

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/ios#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

ON section this.
Step 1: Turn on the Google Apps Script Execution API

Hope it helps you.